# comparing two tables with mysql

Tags: javascript, mysql, database, pymysql

I tried to search for an answer to this but I'm not sure if there are any answers to this question because I'm not quite sure how to word it correctly... Here I have two tables

Recipe ingredient table

```
Recipe_id|ingredient_id
ifqvv    |1
ifqvv    |2
```

User ingredient table

```
User_id|ingredient_id
1      |1
1      |2
2      |1
3      |3
```

I need to compare these table to where if both recipe and user ingredients_id are a complete match it will return a 1, or if the ingredients are greater than 0 it'll return a 2, and 3 for no matches. For Example, a query for User 1 will return a 1, User 2 a 2, and User 3 a 3. I'm not sure if this is something I'll have to code but I was told by someone that this is possible with little information, which led me here

Comment: This is generally easier to do in application code.. Run two queries store it in arrays and do some kind of counting array difference..  I assume you use server side javascript like Node.js ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you also have a `user` table, you could achieve this by cross-joining the `user` with the `recipe_ingredients` table and then left-joining the `user_ingredients` table, e.g.:

```sql
SELECT u.user_id, ri.recipe_id,
       COUNT(ui.ingredient_id) AS available_ingredients, -- Number of ingredients the user has that are required to cook this recipe
       COUNT(ri.ingredient_id) AS required_ingredients,  -- Number of ingredients that are required to cook this recipe
       CASE
         WHEN COUNT(ui.ingredient_id) = COUNT(ri.ingredient_id) THEN 'can_cook'
         WHEN COUNT(ui.ingredient_id) > 0 THEN 'has_some_ingredients'
         ELSE 'has_no_ingredients'
       END AS state
FROM users u
CROSS JOIN recipe_ingredients ri
LEFT JOIN user_ingredients ui ON(ri.ingredient_id = ui.ingredient_id AND u.user_id = ui.user_id)
GROUP BY u.user_id, ri.recipe_id
ORDER BY u.user_id, ri.recipe_id
```

If you want to limit it to a certain user / recipe, just use a where clause:

```sql
WHERE u.user_id = 1 AND ri.recipe_id = 'ifqvv'
```

You can try it live here: [DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/mBnp88rnusgv7AHFamfYcu/0)

If you don't have an `users` table then you can replace
`FROM users u` with `FROM (SELECT DISTINCT user_id FROM user_ingredients) u`
[DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/xbzcCHoFZ22YtvZ9WvbMTj/1)

Comment: Thanks a lot, I had something similar to this but I was stuck on what to do after the case statement.